# Tone.js - Weird arrhythmia

Tags: angular, audio, tone.js

I'm trying to implement a simple metronome in Angular 9 with tone.js, but it seems that some type of arrhythmia is happening during the execution... 
I don't know if i'm missing something in the implementation.

Here is my code:

```
    playMetronome(): void {
        Tone.Transport.bpm.value = 120;

        Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat(() => {
          const player = new Tone.Player("./../../assets/sounds/tick.mp3").toMaster();
          player.autostart = true;
        }, "4n");

        Tone.Transport.start();
    }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: my guess is that you somehow start this several times

Comment: I think that the weird behavior is because i used Tone.Player with a mp3 file into scheduleRepeat... Anyway, i removed Tone.Player, and i added Tone.Synth, in this way i build my own tick sound of metronome... No arrhythmia after did it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "time" parameter of Tones Transport mechanism, otherwise the timing will be unstable. E.g.:

```
// instantiate the player
const play1 = new Tone.Player(<url>).toDestination();
// schedule the events
Tone.Transport.schedule(time => play1.start(time), 0);
Tone.Transport.schedule(time => play1.start(time), '0:2');
// set tempo
Tone.Transport.bpm.value = 220;
// set loop & repeat
Tone.Transport.loopEnd = '1m';
Tone.Transport.loop = true;
// start transport
Tone.Transport.start();
```

Find a stackblitz example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-metronome-mki

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will try to implement your suggestion and i return with results!